# clang-format groups and empty lines

Tags: clang-format

I have a question about clang-format (currently using version 3.8). Assuming the following rules in `.clang-format`:

```
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '"a/.*"'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '"b/.*"'
    Priority:        1
```

and the following example file:

```
#include "a/foo.h"
#include "b/bar.h"
```

then clang-format sorts correctly, i.e. first the include with `b/` and then `a/`. However, if I add an empty line:

```
#include "a/foo.h"

#include "b/bar.h"
```

this no longer works. Is there a way to force clang-format to ignore this empty line and sort disregarding it.

Bonus question: If I wanted to add an empty line after each group as defined in `.clang-format`, would that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible in clang-format version 3.8.  You may want to add yourself to the CC list of the following feature request: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32271

EDIT: It is now possible with `IncludeBlocks: Regroup`

Comment: Thanks for opening that bug. I'll be sure to watch it for a resolution.